# AngularJS - get current element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, hover

I have 4 templates, each of them has mouse actions:

```
ng-mouseover="enableDragging()" ng-mouseleave="disableDragging()"
```

Inside those functions, I change some scope variable and I want to be able to add a class using jQuery. Can I do it without passing a parameter and without updating some scope variable (or some other workaround).

What I mean is some plain way of using a class or id located in all 4 templates, without naming which template I'm on.

Incase perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way the story is:
I want to change some scope variable AND the css of a div when entering that div, and rollback that change when I leave the div.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass **$event** as a parameter to `ng-mouseover` callback function to get the element reference.

```
ng-mouseover="enableDragging($event)"
```

**in controller**

```
function enableDragging(event){
  var element = event.target;
  console.log(element)
}
```

If you want to update the class of Dom node based on a condition, you can try [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.